# How to repair assist handle on 2015 Toyota Avalon

Tags: toyota, repair, interior, avalon

Not a huge problem obviously, which is why I'm alright with doing it myself. It seems like the spring has just come out of its socket. [Album here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptU1Q.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Basically, it doesn't spring back up and if you'll notice in the second photo there's a small bit of chrome protruding from the bottom that isn't seen on the handles that still work properly.

Is there a way to safely pop the cap off the base so that I can put the spring back into place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real way to fix these kinds of springs once they are broke. Replacement is probably your best course of action.

I think the easiest/cheapest way to go about it is to just replace the handle with one from a junk yard (pick-a-part, what have ya). The piece above the split should be a cap. From looking at it, it should fold up, so separates at the split. Use a small, thin screwdriver to pry up on it at the split (a thin knife might work well, too). Once the cap is moved up, you'll find a large screw underneath of it. Unscrew it from both ends and it will come off readily.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Once I got it off I saw that there was no way I could really pop the spring back into place. It was a pain to replace but it's done now.

Comment: @Bratchley - Thanks for reporting back and closing this out. I'm glad you were able to get it fixed.